# Programa em python quesoma o fatorial de números impares até o digitado pelo usuário

Tags: python, soma, fatorial

Devo pedir para o usuário digitar um número ímpar e retornar na tela a soma do fatorial de todos os ímpares até o digitado pelo usuário.

Fiz a parte que valida se o número digitado é ímpar e a função que calcula o fatorial do número digitado. Mas não sei como fazer o resto. Não consegui nem pensar na lógica da outra função. Fiz esse código:

```
def fatorial(x):
    result=1
    for i in range(x):
        result=result*(x-i)    
    return result

'''def fatorial(x):
    x=x-2
    while x>1:
        fat=fat*a
        a-=1 - Não deu certo'''
a=int(input("Digite o número: "))
while a%2!=1:
    a=int(input("Número não impar, digite outro número: "))
    while a<0:
        a=int(input("Número menor que zero, digite outro número: "))
else:
    b=fatorial(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendo a função que calcula o fatorial e o número digitado N, basta fazer um `for` pelos números ímpares de 1 a N, e ir somando o fatorial deles:

```
def fatorial(x):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, x + 1):
        result *= i
    return result

while True:
    n = int(input('digite o número'))
    if n % 2 == 0 or n <= 0:
        print('número deve ser impar e maior que zero, digite outro')
    else: break

soma = 0
for i in range(1, n + 1, 2):
    soma += fatorial(i)

print(soma)
```

Repare que para verificar se o número digitado é ímpar eu fiz um *loop* infinito (`while True`), que só é interrompido se o número for ímpar (se for par, imprime a mensagem e pede que digite novamente). Também incluí a verificação se é negativo, pois parece só poder aceitar positivos.

Depois fiz um `for` usando um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), que começa em 1 e vai até `n`, pulando de 2 em 2 (assim eu sei que vai percorrer somente os ímpares até `n`). Tive que colocar `n + 1` porque o valor final não é incluso no `range`.

Entendo que por ser um exercício, *pode ser* que queiram que você itere de 1 em 1 e teste se o número é impar, algo assim:

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        soma += fatorial(i)
```

Mas sinceramente, a menos que seja exigência do exercício iterar de 1 em 1 e usar o operador `%`, isso é desnecessário, pois se eu começo de um número ímpar e só quero iterar pelos ímpares, basta pular de 2 em 2.

Veja também que mudei a função que calcula o fatorial, para começar o `range` com 2 (começar com 1 é desnecessário  porque multiplicar por 1 é redundante). Da forma que você fez até funciona, mas em um `range` é possível controlar o valor inicial e final, então acho que fica melhor assim. Se `n` for 1, ele nem entra no `for` e o resultado é 1.

Ah sim, você disse que estava tentando fazer uma função para calcular a soma. Neste caso ficaria:

```
def soma_fat(n):
    soma = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1, 2):
        soma += fatorial(i)
    return soma

n = # ler valor do n
print(soma_fat(n))
```

---

Se quiser, você também pode calcular a soma usando [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) juntamente com uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
soma = sum(fatorial(i) for i in range(1, n + 1, 2))
```

---

Também é possível dar uma pequena "otimizada". Ao calcular o fatorial de 3, por exemplo, multiplicamos 1 * 2 * 3, e depois temos que calcular o fatorial de 5, fazendo 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 (ou seja, as primeiras multiplicações serão feitas novamente).

Dá para evitar esse retrabalho guardando o fatorial do último número calculado, e só fazer as multiplicações que faltam:

```
# ler n usando o while True acima

soma = 1
fat = 1
for i in range(3, n + 1, 2):
    fat *= i * (i - 1)
    soma += fat
print(soma)
```

Se `n` for menor que 3 (ou seja, se for 1), ele nem entra no `for` e o resultado é 1. Se for maior ou igual a 3, o *loop* vai atualizando o fatorial (multiplicando os valores que faltam) e somando ao total.

Comment: Cara, muito bom. Obrigada pelas explicações e pelo detalhamemto.